# Add value to input popover Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor

Use bootstrap popover with MeteorJS and have trouble

I Can't assign some value that coming from collection to input value (where 
{{title}} is some `string` like `wwww`). In `html` of form **POPOVER** doesnt exist `value="///"` ,but in my form I see this `value="some title"`

```
<template name="one">
    <div class="popover-markup">
        <div class=" trigger ">
            Edit
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-popover hide">
        <form class="form">
            <input name="title" id="post_edit_title" value="{{title}}" />
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

Template.one.onRendered(function(){
    $('.popover-markup > .trigger').popover({
    html : true,
    content: function() {
        return $('.content-popover').html();
    },
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right'
});
```

EDIT:

```
Meteor.publish("posts_levels", function(){
    return Posts.find();
});

<template name="www">
{{#each level}}
   {{> one}}
{{/each}}
</template>

Template.www.onCreated(function(){
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
      self.subscribe('posts_levels');
  });
 });
```

Comment: I see you are reference `{{#each level}}` where do you define `level` and does each `level` have a `title` property?

Comment: yes yes, all ok, my form have {{title}}, but when popover shows, title in form doesnt exist

Comment: are you saying you can see the value you expect in the HTML DOM when you use Chrome's inspect element, but it doesn't show when you actually mouseover the trigger?

Comment: if I put `form` in template with `display:block` I can see title in value and in DOM, but when I click on button to show popover with this form, than `value="smth"` doesn't exist in DOM

Answer (score 0):

Create a Template Helper which exposes `title` to your template. [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers)

```
Template.one.helpers({
  title: function() {
    return Collection.findOne({/* select your data*/}).prop;
  }
});
```

Comment: :) if you think that I have nothing in my input u are wrong, I have template level sub, so all ok, the problem that I havent got `value` with `value` in popover

Comment: as I said I have my data in title, why you sugest me to do the same ?

Comment: Template level sub only ensures your client minimongo will have the data available, but you still need to apply the data to your template (1 option is using a template helper like I suggested). Seems like there is more to this problem you have not yet described. Please provide all Template functions, helpers, events, and server side publish methods.